# Crystal Reports 2 column crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports

Using crosstab expert in CRpts, populating the columns selection with 2 column names and using preview, report has I cannot tell what is what.  Report has helpdesk total by date and out of that total there is a group count for another dept. Report looks great with one column selected.  However, once I select a column fr db and select it to the columns with Crosstab expert, the columns in the report preview are displayed but hard to tell what is what since I get No and Yes columns.  I also have Keep Groups together, column totals on top, and Row totals on left "checked" out.
I want to be have:  grand toatl column(for helpdesk)  total for Dist.  Classrooms afected totals

Can you help?  I am also new to CR and have not been able to make a "hit" researching.

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't understand the problem.  Can you give us a specific example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, I want a report to look like:

```
   (col 1)     (col 2)     (col 3
```

Date    Group      District    Classes Affected

Crosstab expert has:  2 rows, 2 summaries(sum on date and grandtotal on top), 1 col(which works great with only col 2 used as column but not when I include col 3).

District is count of district's in group
Classes Affected is count of groups count.

Is this better?